# JSON deserialization to inherited types

Tags: .net, json, deserialization, javascriptserializer, strong-typing

I have a data table in my database where I store various settings. Since they are of any type (even complex object graphs) I decided to store their values as serialized JSON strings.

Let's say that I serialized a `List<ItemBase>`. Serialized string looks just fine. But the problem is that list items are of various types that are inherited from `ItemBase` (which may as well be abstract for what I care).

### Question

Which (de)serialization class/library should I use so my JSON strings will be correctly deserialized to correct object instances.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[json.net](http://json.codeplex.com/) has the ability to [preserve references](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/PreserveObjectReferences.html)

And it supports [storing the type](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2010/08/13/json-net-3-5-release-8-3-5-final.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+jamesnewtonking+%28James+Newton-King%29)

Comment: Well preserving references isn't what I'm looking for and is a different functionality. But type inheritance is...

Comment: As I understand the documentation the `TypeNameHandling` setting makes json.net store the typename. And you talked about "complex object graphs" so I think you need that feature too.